# Deserializing abstract property from JSON request body, based on another property from that body

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, jackson, json-deserialization

How to properly deserialize an object from JSON (using Jackson) when it has an abstract property of which the conrete implementation depends on another property from that request body?

This is probably best described on an example.

Request body for my REST endpoint includes a property which is an abstract type with multiple concrete implementations which should be deserialized based on the `discriminator` property:

```
@Getter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SomeRequestBody {

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @NumberFormat
    private final String discriminator;

    @NotNull
    private final SomeAbstractClass someAbstractClass;

}
```

Abstract class in question

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public abstract class SomeAbstractClass{

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    protected final String commonProperty;

}
```

Example implementation of the abstract class

```
@Getter
public class ConcreteImplementationA extends SomeAbstractClass {

    @Builder
    @JsonCreator
    public ConcreteImplementationA(
        @NotNull @NotBlank @JsonProperty("commonProperty") String commonProperty,
        @NotNull @NotBlank @JsonProperty("specificProperty") Date specificProperty) {
            super(commonProperty);
            this.specificProperty = specificProperty;
    }

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private final String specificProperty;

}
```

What I tried...

```
@Getter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SomeRequestBody {

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @NumberFormat
    private final String discriminator;

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "discriminator")
    @JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ConcreteImplementationA.class, name = "1"),
        Other implementations...)
    })
    @NotNull
    private final SomeAbstractClass someAbstractClass;

}
```

However, I'm getting the following exception:

```
"Type definition error: [simple type, class abc.SomeRequestBody]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `abc.SomeRequestBody`, problem: Internal error: no creator index for property 'someAbstractClass' (of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty)\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 8, column: 1]"
```

What is the proper way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was not a problem with deserialization of that abstract property, but immutable properties and Lombok's `@AllArgsConstructor` not working well with Jackson. I have created a @JsonCreator annotated constructor instead of using the annotation and now it works fine.

Comment: Instead of building your own constructor, adding this should also have worked  `@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__({@JsonCreator}))`, at least for me it worked.

Comment: If most of your objects are immutable like this and you don't want to have to add config details to every class ... you can create a `lombik.config` file with the property `lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties=true` in it.  This will cause lombok to add Java annotations to the constructor arguments, naming them, which Jackson is able to use.